# Model selection in R, AICCc weight of 1.00

Tags: r, model-selection, aic

When doing model selection in R with MuMIn, I get AICc weight of 1. I've been told this is impossible to justify biologically, and can't be right. Why have I got a weight of 1, and how can I check my model/methods for robustness?
I checked for colinearity and VIF and all was good.

```
head(contr)
   SEX TMENT TIME TT  ID     GROUP   PROP       SQRT
1 MALE   NON    A N0 102      acid 0.0033 0.05744563
2 MALE   NON    A N0 102    alkane 0.0434 0.20832667
3 MALE   NON    A N0 102    ketone 0.0108 0.10392305
4 MALE   NON    A N0 102  aldehyde 0.0014 0.03741657
5 MALE   NON    A N0 102   alcohol 0.0196 0.14000000
6 MALE   NON    A N0 102 benzenoid 0.0303 0.17406895

#Candidate models
C1<- lme(PROP~TMENT, random=~1|ID, data=contr)
C2<- lme(PROP~TIME, random=~1|ID, data=contr)
C3<- lme(PROP~TMENT*TIME, random=~1|ID, data=contr)
C4<- lme(PROP~TMENT*GROUP, random=~1|ID, data=contr)
C5<- lme(PROP~TIME*GROUP, random=~1|ID, data=contr)

cand.mods<- list(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)
model.selection<- model.sel(cand.mods)
mod.avg<- model.avg(cand.mods, fit=TRUE, subset=cumsum(weight)<= .95)
summary(mod.avg)


Call:
model.avg(object=cand.mods, fit=TRUE, subset=cumsum(weight)<= 0.95)

Component model call: 
lme.formula(fixed = <5 unique values>, data=contr, random= ~1 | ID)

Component models: 
    df  logLik     AICc  delta weight
135 28 1282.77 -2508.62   0.00      1
124 67 1281.83 -2424.46  84.16      0
3    4  914.04 -1820.07 688.56      0
2    7  903.02 -1791.99 716.64      0
236 12  887.13 -1750.09 758.53      0

Term codes: 
      group        time       tment  group:time group:tment  time:tment 
          1           2           3           4           5           6
```

Comment: I imagine that some rounding has occurred - the weight for your best model is very close to 1, and the weights for the other models are all very close to zero.  Can you access the weights directly from the mod.avg dataframe to check? e.g. mod.avg$weight

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the weight of the top model says 1.000000e+00, and the next one down says 5.302930e-19. However, I have a reviewer saying that 1.0 is impossible, and I don't know how to respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you get a weight of 1 because one of your models has a much lower AICc than the others, and its weight has been rounded to 1.

In terms of responding to the review you mentioned:  Instead of reporting the weight as 1, report it as 1.000 or similar - follow the guidelines for the journal you have submitted to, for example, most journals specify reporting statistics to 3 decimal places.  In your response to the review you can also mention that the actual weight is very close to 1, and rounds to 1 up to 19 decimal places (or similar).  I'm sure the reviewer will be happy with this, and understand that it makes sense to present the rounded result - he/she probably just wants to make sure you understand AIC model selection properly.